# error installing ruby old version 2.0.0-p247

Tags: ruby, rbenv, ruby-2.0

I am trying to run command

```
 rbenv install 2.0.0-p247
```

I tried to follow several steps by googling the errors that I faced but I am still not able to resolve the error

I got this error

BUILD FAILED (macOS 11.4 using ruby-build 20210804)

```
Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/xm/rfncj90s56x8d1wdj0sl_0w40000gn/T/ruby-build.20210814020658.2987.F4rCnt
Results logged to /var/folders/xm/rfncj90s56x8d1wdj0sl_0w40000gn/T/ruby-build.20210814020658.2987.log

Last 10 log lines:
compiling ancdata.c
compiling raddrinfo.c
installing default socket libraries
compiling constants.c
1 warning generated.
linking shared-object ripper.bundle
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib'
linking shared-object socket.bundle
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib'
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

The log file mentioned above has content:

> https://easyupload.io/gygw5y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby 2.0.0 is very much past its end of life, so I'm assuming you have a specific reason you need install it. Otherwise, you are much better off installing a modern, supported version such as 2.7.x or 3.0.x.

Older versions of ruby were built with `openssl@1.0`. After 1.0 went end of life, `ruby-build` had a breaking change to require `openssl@1.1`. This means that ruby versions < 2.4 can no longer be installed/built directly using ruby-build (i.e., rbenv). This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1353) has details.

Homebrew has removed its `openssl@1.0` formula, but you can still install it via an rbenv tap. The following *might* work for you, though the comments in the issue report mixed results depending on the version of Command Line Tools being used.

```
brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.0)" 2.0.0-p247
```

Note: if you are running on an M1 (Apple Silicon) Mac, you might be out of luck. AFIK, there's no intention of getting openssl@1.0 to to work on Apple Silicon.

Comment: In general, if you want to compile outdated software, it is easiest do that in an environment that is contemporary with that outdated software, and has actually been tested. That means compiler, libraries, operating system, build tools, etc. should be from the same time as the software. This may also require you to use hardware from that same time in case the older OS does not support the current hardware.